# Jenkins pipeline multiline shell with escape character

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm running into a weird issues with a pipeline script. I have a multi line  sh blob like

```
sh """
   git tag -fa \\"${version}\\" -m \\"Release of ${version}\\"
"""
```

And this somehow runs as:

```
+ git tag -fa '"1.0-16-959069f'
error: Terminal is dumb, but EDITOR unset
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

So its dropping the `-m` and message. I've tried single escapes, double escapes, nothing seems to work.

Comment: Does simple `sh """ git tag -fa '${version}' -m 'Release of ${version}' """` work?

Comment: nope. I tried single quotes, and i also tried escaping only once.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why this worked but this did

```
def tagGithub(String version) {
    def exec = """
    git tag -d ${version} || true
    git push origin :refs/tags/${version}

    # tag new version
    git tag -fa ${version} -m "Release of ${version}"
    git push origin --tags
    """

    sh exec
}
```

Something with the inline jenkins groovy interpolation seems busted, doing the interpolation in another var and then executing it worked

Comment: So the way I was calculating the `version` , it had a new line char at the end. So I added `version.trim()` and it started working.

Comment: @IshuGupta Thank you . exactly same with you